# Can the "Flag for moderator attention" have a feedback mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

So lets say I flag a question for moderator attention. What happens after that is pretty opaque. I think the process can be made less opaque by the following:

1. Having a list of what I flagged and the message I sent in the "recent" tab of my profile would let me know what I flagged.
2. The ability for moderators to note that they have seen the flag. [Moderators have a queue of flagged items and get an indicator that something has been flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/details-about-the-flagging-mechanism/2841#2841). Can users have an indication that they flagged something, and a moderator looked at that flag
3. A moderator should be able to comment on a flag. They would probably only do this in fuzzy cases. Flagrant abuse, obvious duplicate questions, etc don't need commentary.

Comment: I'd just like some indication of whether my flags were considered useful or not.  If they're not considered useful, I don't want to keep wasting other peoples' time with them.

Comment: The flag number is now clickable on your user profile page. This takes you to the history.

Comment: This appears to have been even further completed.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223601/241697

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now handled by the flagging history.

You can get to it via the following URL scheme:

```
http://example.com/users/flag-weight/{your-userid-for-that-site}
```

It will list the following:

- **moderator attention flags** - Total count of flags raised on the field
- **deemed valid** - Count of when a moderator has marked valid/agreed
- **deemed invalid** - Count of those disagreed with
- **disputed** - flags other users have disagreed with (does not affect your flag weight)
- **posts marked as spam**
- **posts marked as offensive**

Some of these may not yet appear in the flagging history if you haven't flagged in such a way.

Comment: what about deemed helpful? what does it mean?

Comment: helpful is valid @muh

Answer (score 10):

AS with the other moderators, if I feel a flag requires some form of feedback, I will either send an email to the flagging user or I will leave a comment on the question as a heads up (this is especially useful for when a topic has multiple flags).

Although I think a feedback mechanism would be nice, if it gets implemented in some form like a "private message" you would end up having users all asking (all over again) for the private messaging feature available to everyone.

Comment: I don't buy the slippery slope argument. Besides, for months there *was* no moderator flag and users were required to email the team with any issue that they had. When we did get the mod flags, it allowed users to notify the moderators of problems with a few clicks, as opposed to composing and sending an email. It also enables all moderators to instantly see what issues are yet resolved, look into them, and clear the flag when done (so that someone else doesn't try to "fix" the situation again). I see providing user feedback as a logical continuation of this system.

Comment: There would be no need for a private messaging feature, imo. It would be enough to have an additional tab in the recent-activity page.

Answer (score 7):

I have occasionally wanted some way to respond to the flagger without needing to do so in a comment. As flags do have a bit of an expectation to privacy, I don't feel comfortable addressing the user directly, so I've ended up just posting a vague response that sometimes feels out of place in the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I for one reply to a flag if required as a comment to the actual question. In other case performing the action requested by the flag indicates me accepting it, and no response to it means it is not valid and being ignored.

I don't necessarily feel this is required. If the problem is very serious all the moderators have their contact details available in their profiles, or the team can be e-mailed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe now [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) could be used for this purpose. It would still require a "invite user to chat" feature for mods, which I think was already requested for everyone anyway...