# Can we get a confirmation that flagging a post for spam has worked?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, spam

When I flag a post for mod attention, a little box pops up that says "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" or similar.  But when I flag a post as spam, there's no such box.  In fact, there's no indication that my action was noticed at all.  I end up flagging again just to make sure the "You can only flag this post once." box appears, which is an awkward workaround.  Can we get some kind of indication that spam flags have been received?

EDIT:
This feature request goes for offensive/abuse/hate speech flags as well, since they apparently have the same no-confirmation behavior.

Comment: Yeah, now that flagging no longer causes a -1, the only way to tell (other than flagging again) is the 10k tools.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/can-the-flag-for-moderator-attention-have-a-feedback-mechanism

Comment: @mmy, it does count as a -1

Comment: @Jon, I'm less excited about the proposals in that second link.  Once I flag something, there's really nothing more I can do, whether the mods take any action or not.  So, I see no reason keep track of/follow up on stuff I flag.  As for the first link, I admit that my search-fu failed me, _mea culpa_.

Comment: @Down: Last I checked, it didn't affect the vote number on the left (but it did affect reputation). Is that not the case?

Comment: @mmyers It has had a delayed effect on the vote count (quite significantly delayed as has been reported), but I was never aware of any time that it was fully removed.

Comment: @mmy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag popup form will show a spinner while the request processes, and a "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" message will show upon successful vote.

Good suggestion!

Comment: This will be deployed tonight.