# Show flags in profile history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, recent-activity, flag-history

Inspired by [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49568/can-we-get-a-confirmation-that-flagging-a-post-for-spam-has-worked) about seeing confirmation of successful flagging.

I would like to see flags I've submitted recorded on my profile, maybe under the Activity tab.  It's easy enough to find them using the 10K tools, but for the sites on which I don't have 10K yet it'd make finding the flagged posts a whole lot easier.

As justification, consider the situation in which you flag a post, edit something offense out of it and someone rolls the offensive bit back in.  I would want to pay attention to that and get a moderator on it to lock the post or something (short of entering into a rollback war).

**EDIT:**
Wasn't thinking about the public aspect of our profiles (...)  In light of that it'd definitely need to be on a private tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now see this and it's visible only to you and moderators.

Go to your profile and you'll see something like this beside your avatar:

> profile views ∞
>   helpful flags 360

Clicking through will show the summary and history of all that you have flagged.

Comment: Awwwww, I want infinite views on *my* profile. =(

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a way could be implemented to track your own flags (If I really think it's a problem post, I might favourite the question in question in order to monitor it, but this is a workaround at best), but I don't agree with putting it right in your profile.

For some actions like Close Votes which are made public, I would agree with maybe showing them in the profile. But I don't think flagging should be. Flagging for spam, offensive, or moderator is meant to be anonymous, like voting on posts. Making it visible to the public in your profile would be betraying those people who enjoy silently flagging things. Sure, the information on the Activity tab will eventually be pushed off, but it's still public record of information which some people may not want to be all that public. And if some spiteful soul does spot your action, then, well, he might act on that spitefulness.

Comment: Hmm, that's a very good point that I didn't think about...

Answer (score 1):

I support showing them in your private profile, but remember that they disappear in 48 hours if the post didn't reach the threshold (6), and if it did reach the threshold, I'm not sure the system keeps track of it anymore.

So it would basically be only for flags placed in the last 48 hours.

Comment: Yep, realize that.  Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Answer (score 0):

The flagging activity can now be seen in the flagging summary that appears when you click on your flag weight.