# Add flagging activity to one's own recent activity?

Tags: feature-request, flags, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show flags in profile history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49571/show-flags-in-profile-history)

Would it be possible to add flagging activity to one's own recent activity tab?

It is really not a very big deal if not, but here are a few modest arguments:

- flagging simply ís community activity (and the summary would be more complete),
- maybe useful for your own "statistics",
- being able to review your own flag action,
- to remember which questions you have flagged (in order to see if there has anything changed since),
- ... ?

Furthermore: whether this flagging activity should also be visible to other users could be a discussion.