# Are these questions about link to flagging history exact duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, flag-history

I am having hard time trying to figure what made two questions duplicates?

Here is how I read these

1. **fix a minor glitch** in a generally perfectly working *feature*
   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-not-shown-in-the-profile-when-the-flag-weight-is-100
   The glitch is: link to flagging history usually shown to users with non-empty history disappears when flag weight meets some irrelevant condition
2. **make a major change** to a generally perfectly working *feature*
   [Permanent Flag Weight History Link on User Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117008/permanent-flag-weight-history-link-on-user-profile)
   The proposed change is: display link to flagging history always, even when users has it empty

I can grok that change proposed in second question would "fix" the glitch reported the first one. But is this a valid reason to close first question as an exact duplicate of the second?

---

BTW here is a suggestion I see in [closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-not-shown-in-the-profile-when-the-flag-weight-is-100):

> This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.

Great, fine - I [attempted proposed merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117014/165773) in the question declared as "identical". Somehow though I don't feel like this is a "merge" indeed. Somehow I feel like I attempted to answer two **different** questions.

Comment: Note that I edited the second question that was initially tagged [meta-tag:feature-request], after my [meta-tag:bug] report was closed as a duplicate of it. I'm honestly not sure whether one.beat.consumer wants to display the flag history link all the time or only when the flag history is non-empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exact duplicates.  Clearly the intent of the developers is to [not show the flag history/weight when it's not interesting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#comment195742_80178).  Ignoring implementation details for a moment, that seems to be the feature we should and do have.  I have no problem with that, but #2 apparently does and wants to always see the link.  So #2 wants to propose a new feature to change from "don't show if not interesting" to "always show."

However, that is indeed a feature request, whereas #1 refers to a bug.  Proponents of #1 might accept that it's perfectly fine to not show the link when the flag weight/history is not interesting.  The bug in the implementation is that the criteria for not interesting was `flag weight == 100`.  The example from #1 of 1 flag helpful and one 1 declined is not the same as no history of flags.  It's admittedly a minor issue that you guys might not want to give enough priority to fix, but I maintain that it is indeed a bug.  This isn't asking for a new feature, it's asking you to fix the implementation bug in defining when flag weights/histories are non-interesting.  This is not an **exact** duplicate of #2 and it should be re-opened.

Answer (score -2):

It would have been better to just retag [Flag history not shown in the profile when the flag weight is 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-not-shown-in-the-profile-when-the-flag-weight-is-100) to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as the whole language and angle of the post was a request to change the current behaviour.

And the earlier question it was [closed a duplicate of was just that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/117008/1). Until it was entirely reworded to become a bug report instead of a wish to change the current nature of how and when the link to flag history shows.

What's the difference between these two feature requests? One is for the link to always be accessible. The newer is for it to show when they've raised their first flag.

Comment: I see. As far as I can tell currently things work as designed, [per your past answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92572/165773) _"If you're above... 100, you'll see a value for your flag weight."_

Comment: It really is a bug though, even if you designed it that way.  The intent is clearly to avoid showing a the flag history/weight when it is not interesting.  The bug in the implementation is that the criteria for not interesting was `flag weight == 100`.

Comment: @random 1-st question is updated with [this screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPqMh.jpg) - could you please comment it?

Comment: A bugbear is not the same as a software bug @mic

Comment: @random Is your intent to hide uninteresting flag weights or is it to hide flag weights that just so happen to equal a specific value?  If it's the former then it's a bug in the implementation.  If it's the latter then you correctly implemented a pointless feature.

Comment: Doesn't matter how you're at the starting blocks, when you're at 100, no link is shown. Currently. @mic

Comment: But I argue if that is the spec then it is utterly pointless.  Isn't the real point to hide uninteresting flag weights?