# Where to find moderator replies related to declined flag?

Tags: support, declined-flags, flag-history

A moderator contacted me today via a Comment on an Answer to say that I seemed not to have seen his reply to a flag of mine that he had declined.  Apparently, he had declined several similar ones from me.

I've looked into trying to find and read these moderator replies, now that my attention has been drawn to them, but have had no success.  The closest Meta posting that I could find was [Allow moderators to reply to a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag) which seems to suggest that a year or so ago they were not able to reply to flags.

If I want to see moderator replies to any of my flags where can I find them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile and click the number next to "helpful flags". You should see a message next to the declined flag explaining the reason it was declined. If you cannot see or find "helpful flags" in your profile, navigate to `[domain]/users/flag-summary/[your-user-id]`. For your Meta Stack Overflow profile that link would be: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/215590

Comment: The `helpful flags` number gave me access to the replies that I had not been aware of - thanks for answering so quickly.