# Add blue highlighted number to Featured tab on Questions page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tabs, bountied-tab, questions-page

On the Homepage view, the Featured tab shows a number in blue (on SO) of the number of featured questions.  Please add this icon to the Featured tab on the Questions page also.

[alt text http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/1329/featurehighlight2.png](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/1329/featurehighlight2.png)

**Note:** The main reason for this is so that I'll know if there are any featured questions without having to go to the featured tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. Meta needs to be more consistent with the other sites. If bounty questions are represented by a bluebox-number on SO, they ought to be handled the same here. Perhaps blue isn't the best color (theme-based?), but the idea should be implemented.

Actually, I just noticed that SO's Questions Page also doesn't show the number of featured posts, but it does from the front page (as does Meta). I still support the extending of this feature to the Questions Page regardless.

Comment: Yes, I meant it for all sites, SO would be the most useful for me.

Comment: Definitely a small inconsistency. Good find though!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I agree -- the featured count is now on the question list and the questions tagged list, but only for single tags in the latter case.