# Why are some flags anonymous?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should moderators be able to see who flags an item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37345/should-moderators-be-able-to-see-who-flags-an-item)

I'm a moderator over at Math.SE and I've been getting some annoying flags.

For example, a month or so ago, someone flagged several of my questions with what appears to be out of malice. There have been other cases where a user constantly flags content that I don't see the point of deleting. I would like to know who these users are so I can tell them to cut it out. But rude/offensive and some other categories of flags are anonymous (as far as I can tell) so I can't even identify them.

Why are these flags anonymous, even when I am a moderator of the site?

Comment: Are you talking about comment flags?

Comment: No, I'm also talking about spam / offensive flags on questions, which I think are also anonymous.

Comment: @Qiaochu Ah yes, they are.

Comment: If the user is just spam flagging your questions, it's not actionable anyway.  Just dismiss the flags as invalid and move on.  If the user keeps doing it, their flag weight will eventually get so low that their flags will no longer appear in the mod queue.

Comment: @Robert: AFAIK spam/offensive flags can't be dismissed as invalid.

Comment: The "Dismiss Flags on This Post" dialog is under the "No Further Action..." button of the flagged post in the moderator queue.  The dialog has a Valid and an Invalid button.  It works for spam flags.

Answer (score 3):

They're anonymous to prevent moderators from getting revenge on users. However, if you have a real problem, I suggest you email team@stackexchange.com and ask them to look into it privately. They probably won't release the usernames to you (for the same reason), but a Community Coordinator might do something on your behalf.

Comment: He's an intern.  Maybe he can just yell over the cubicle wall instead.  :-)

Comment: To prevent moderators from getting revenge on users?  I really doubt that.

Comment: @Robert I'm fairly certain that was the reason given two years ago, but it could have changed since then.

Comment: Hm.  Well, if malice ever plays even the smallest part in one of my mod decisions, that's the day I will resign as a moderator.  "Moderator revenge" should be an oxymoron.

Comment: How about insulation from potential accusations of bias?

Comment: That makes more sense; plausible deniability.  Not sure why spam flags get special treatment, though.  A flag is a flag.