# How often do moderators purge entire comment threads?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags, data-analysis

I'm kicking around some ideas for ways to improve comment moderation. As part of one of these ideas, I'd like to get some statistics - specifically, how often do moderators delete entire comment threads in response to a comment flag?

That is hopelessly vague, so here is how I define it (which might be too hard to query, adjust as needed):

- On posts with > 1 comment
- Where at least one of those comments was flagged
- And a moderator responded (wasn't 6-flag or keyword deleted)
- In what percentage of those cases did a moderator take action such that there were no comments remaining on the post? I.e. where there was a point in time, after the first comment flag, where there were 0 undeleted comments on the post?
- Cases where the comments were deleted, such that there were 0 comments on the post, and then someone commented later **should count**.

I know this sounds like a work order (or really awesome homework, if you prefer to think of it that way), so here's my rationale (which **is not the point** of the post, just to provide context): I'm testing out the idea of having a review queue analogous to the LQP review queue, that comment threads where at least one was flagged go to. Then we'd just have a 'purge' / "don't purge" button.

Needs work, and I don't know if it's even plausible - so hence the data request.

Comment: I'll look at pulling some of these numbers. It's not really straight-forward, but I'll dig into it.

Comment: You have a lot more comment flags than I do (mine are mostly on posts), but in the 1,300-something comments I've flagged, I only rarely seen the whole discussion getting nuked. The ones I have seen are those in which there are a *lot* of comments, many of them are flag-worthy, and it's just a huge effort to sort the obsolete from the obsolete-but-helpful, the rude from the impolite-but-constructive, etc. That said, nice question. Would love to hear those numbers, @bluefeet.

Comment: Nuking a comment thread is pretty heavy handed. It is definitely uncommon. The numbers for comment thread nuked % out of all comments deleted would probably be far below 1% of the time.

Comment: If I flag for purge I normally flag the post not a comment. Does this type of flag count in your stat?

Comment: @rene Ideally it would count, but I believe that these are both (a) terribly hard to query for, and (b) should be rare enough among 'normal' users (which aren't you or me) so as not to skew the results too much.

Comment: Straight-out purge, not moved to chat, right?  (Strictly speaking, move to chat leaves one comment -- the chat link -- but I'd rather ask than assume.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm most interesting in straight-out purges, yes.

Comment: In my experience, the common case where an entire comment thread is deleted is when someone flags a *question/answer* with a custom flag saying "you can delete all the comments below", rather than flagging a comment.  (And I feel like I've read somewhere that this is the suggested way to ask a moderator to purge all comments.)  Your criteria would exclude/ignore that case.  You could change "Where at least one of those comments was flagged" to "Where at least one of those comments was flagged, or where the post that the comments are on received a custom flag", but probably it's moot now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't the easiest data to extract from the database, mainly because we don’t have a specific post history type when we purge the comments like we do when we move comments to chat.  But I've attempted to extract this somehow by looking at the percentage of comments deleted by a moderator compared to the total comments on a post.

I'm limiting the results to those that have more than 1 comment and where the moderator deleted more than 50 percent of the total comments.

On to the stats for the past 30 days:

```
+-----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
|                Site Name                | TotalPosts | Mod Deleted 50-70% | Mod Deleted 70-80% | Mod Deleted 80-90% | Mod Deleted 90-100% | Avg # Comment Post Purge |
+-----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| Stack Overflow                          |       1406 |               1178 |                 37 |                 39 |                 152 |                        0 |
| Mathematics                             |         78 |                 51 |                  5 |                  7 |                  15 |                        0 |
| Role-playing Games                      |         59 |                 13 |                  6 |                  8 |                  17 |                        0 |
| Code Review                             |         51 |                 23 |                  5 |                  4 |                  12 |                        0 |
| English Language and Usage              |         45 |                 27 |                  6 |                  5 |                   7 |                        0 |
| Jewish Life and Learning                |         41 |                 13 |                  5 |                  4 |                   6 |                        0 |
| The Workplace                           |         37 |                 14 |                  4 |                  8 |                  11 |                        2 |
| Database Administrators                 |         35 |                  8 |                  6 |                  5 |                  16 |                        0 |
| Super User                              |         35 |                 22 |                  3 |                  5 |                   5 |                        0 |
| Christianity                            |         33 |                 13 |                  0 |                  5 |                   3 |                        0 |
| Computer Science                        |         32 |                 12 |                  2 |                  3 |                   6 |                        0 |
| Physics                                 |         31 |                  7 |                  2 |                  1 |                   8 |                        0 |
| IT Security                             |         23 |                  6 |                  1 |                  3 |                   2 |                        1 |
| Ubuntu                                  |         22 |                  8 |                  1 |                  3 |                  10 |                        0 |
| Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange |         19 |                 14 |                  1 |                  0 |                   4 |                        0 |
| Science Fiction                         |         19 |                 11 |                  1 |                  2 |                   5 |                        0 |
| TeX - LaTeX                             |         18 |                  7 |                  1 |                  2 |                   6 |                        0 |
| Gaming                                  |         17 |                  9 |                  2 |                  3 |                   3 |                        0 |
| German Language and Usage               |         16 |                 11 |                  1 |                  0 |                   4 |                        0 |
| Academia                                |         15 |                  6 |                  0 |                  1 |                   4 |                        0 |
| Software Recommendations Stack Exchange |         13 |                  6 |                  2 |                  1 |                   4 |                        0 |
| Android Enthusiasts                     |         12 |                  3 |                  2 |                  0 |                   2 |                        0 |
| Biblical Hermeneutics                   |         12 |                  5 |                  2 |                  1 |                   4 |                        0 |
| Chemistry                               |         12 |                  5 |                  2 |                  0 |                   3 |                        0 |
| Code Golf                               |         11 |                 10 |                  0 |                  0 |                   1 |                        3 |
| Health Stack Exchange                   |         11 |                  5 |                  1 |                  0 |                   5 |                        0 |
| Unix and Linux                          |         11 |                  7 |                  0 |                  0 |                   3 |                        0 |
| Parenting                               |         10 |                  5 |                  2 |                  1 |                   2 |                        0 |
| Worldbuilding Stack Exchange            |         10 |                  4 |                  4 |                  1 |                   1 |                        1 |
+-----------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

<sup>**Note:** These stats only include sites with 10 or more posts with comment flags.</sup>

One thing to notice is moderators don't typically purge all the comments on a post.  In my experience, they will purge the comments that tend to go off-topic or become too chatty, and add to the noise. You'll also notice that the average number of comments added post purge is relatively low.  I'd take a guess that it's because a conversation is most likely over by the time it gets to the attention of a moderator.

### Related:

- [How has "move comments to chat" affected users' behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261085/how-has-move-comments-to-chat-affected-users-behavior)

Comment: Interesting, I thought it'd be much higher. Thank you so much for digging this up!

Comment: Thanks for running this down. If I had to guess, I'd say a large percentage of the 100% deletions are of the simple bug-fixing variety: "A: You have an error in your answer; it should be blah blah blah. B: Thanks, @A. Fixed!" I know I have flagged lots of those as obsolete.