# Looking for stats related to possibly coordinated comments flagging

Tags: support, meta, statistics, account-suspension, comment-flags

Related: [Why was Robert Harvey suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336339/why-was-robert-harvey-suspended)

I would like to get some statistics about [comments of this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/102937/robert-harvey?tab=activity&sort=comments) that were deleted in two weeks between October, 8 and October, 22. Specifically, I would want to learn:

- How many of these comments were deleted by moving to chat, by moderators, by regular users flags, and by the author.
- How many flags were cast on these deleted comments.
- How many different users cast these flags.
- How many flags were cast by top 3 (or better top 5 or 10) of these users.

I expect requested stats to help me estimate how probable it is that some kind of coordinated comments flagging is going on at MSE lately.

Comment: side note to those who might not know: diamond moderators can see who cast comment flag [since July 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313155/165773)

Comment: I've cast a multitude of flags on both comments and answers and that was all very coordinated. Now what?

Comment: I would also like know this for comments that was deleted from this answer,   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334636/132223

Comment: @rene now let [site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) take a closer look on that and make their mind on whether it was okay or not. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: @JJJ nope, at this point I am not (yet) interested in older stats - only willing to get some data helping to estimate whether this is something worth to be concerned about

Comment: @gnat so if I happen to be on the side that tried to keep exchanges respectful instead of adding more fuel to this dumpster fire I'm now at risk for seeing consequences for that? Happy witch hunting ...

Comment: @rene do I understand it correctly that you equate site moderators reviewing particular comment flags to witch hunting?

Comment: In the way you phrased this question, yes. You assume ill-intent and invite them to go on witch hunting.

Comment: @rene I object against this interpretation. The way you say it was definitely not on my mind, nor I can find anything in the wording of this post that can be interpreted as such. As mentioned in [my prior comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336409/looking-for-stats-related-to-possibly-coordinated-comments-flagging#comment1113283_336409) "at this point I am... only willing to get some data helping to estimate whether this is something worth to be concerned about". If something in this request may possibly misread as something different, please let me know and I'll try to correct

Comment: The only thing I can offer is to leave out the reference to the specific user and ask if between the start of the incident till now, there have been patterns on comment flags that would indicate mob flagging. I would mention that MSE had one mod removed, one mod resigned, leaving two to handle the outburst. It was clear a lot of rude stuff entered the system, how did we do as a community, despite being low on mod capacity. An answer could reveal that certain chatrooms organized flagging or that 3 users took 80% of the comment flagging load.

Comment: @rene I am sorry but specific user makes a critical point in my request and dropping them off will essentially make stats useless for me. Thing is, I have seen many "too heated" comments from different users lately and stats on these would obscure things I want to learn about too much (I have no slightest interest to learn about deletion of obviously poor comments). This specific user provides just the kind of data I am interested in, because I know of their ability to self control and because I have seen their claim that they consciously tried to abstain of rough edges in comments wording

Comment: @rene I totally agree - it's witch hunting and the site has taken a sinister turn. When previously sound and reliable people are trying to dig up dirt and it's gathering momentum, I don't know what we can do.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I can only repeat what I have asked above, do I understand it correctly that you equate site moderators reviewing particular comment flags to witch hunting?

Comment: @gnat site moderators have already reviewed them, that's why they issued a suspension. You seem to be requesting confidential information and for what? To be able to then accuse people of coordinated flagging? This sort of detail has never been public. Why change that now? Haven't we had enough problems because things that should be private have been handled in public? Do we really need yet another episode of the same?

Comment: @terdon I have an experience with similar reviews (not to the point of being suspended but still) and I can assure you that in cases like that it may be helpful to double-check. I honestly can't imagine how additional moderator scrutiny may do any harm

Comment: You're not asking for additional moderator scrutiny. You are asking for things to be made public that are best kept private. It really comes down to whether or not you trust the mods. And, seeing as none of us trust SE anymore, so there is nobody to escalate to, if you don't trust the mods either, then there's even less point in asking for this. You would have no reason to believe anything they say. So I just can't see any point to asking for data you wouldn't believe anyway.

Comment: @terdon quoting what I am asking: "How many flags were cast on these deleted comments.

How many different users cast these flags.

How many flags were cast by top 3 (or better top 5 or 10) of these users." I can't see what harm could be in making this public (especially assuming that at this point I find it entirely possible that outcome will be that there is no coordination worth worrying about). As for the trust, it has nothing to do with this, it may be that moderators did not notice something useful and I am only willing to check whether there was a mistake or not

Comment: @gnat I'd honestly be more interested in anonymized cluster analysis, i.e. correlation in flagging between users and posts, personally

Comment: @SébastienRenauld that would likely reveal only natural / sensible correlation where flags cast by group of most active site readers would tend to cluster around comments posted by those who tend to be snarky / negative. I posted this request to estimate whether it is worth digging deeper into more gray area

Comment: @gnat yes, you posted this to go digging, assuming there is wrong doing. Like we don't have enough problems on this site. I have been targeted on this site and single handedly blamed for flagging comments and getting them deleted. How people know what I flag is beyond me and I don't think I have enough flags to flag the number of comments that are deleted. Inadvertently this post is hurting me. You weren't to know what's been going on.

Comment: @terdon _This sort of detail has never been public. Why change that now? Haven't we had enough problems because things that should be private have been handled in public?_  I don't think it should be made public, that would make this a witch hunt. However, I do feel an audit should be made about the concerns raised in this question and dealt with internally.

Comment: @gnat thanks for posting this.  It certainly _looks_ like some unsavory things are going on with coordinated flagging on Meta, but appearances can be deceiving.  Getting some stats would really help.

Comment: @YvetteColomb you probably need more experience with flagging. Then you will learn that mod review is the best thing for flagger. No matter if it's positive or negative, it helps learn how to do better. I cast tens thousands flags on multiple sites and I still keep checking flag history and learning. I dropped worrying about possible negative reviews few years ago and recommend you do the same. If you feel anxious try to convince self that it will be positive and will confirm that you're doing it right. If it later turns negative, just try to figure how to do better next time

Comment: ...you see, with right attitude there is just no place for anxiety

Answer (score 34):

One of the main reasons we're in this mess is because SE chose to disregard one of the oldest most cherished rules in the network: we do not discuss the details of moderation actions in public. Can we please try to do better and stop trying to drag all the ugly into the light?

A user was given a short suspension by the MSE moderators. The details are already [more public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336339/203101) than they ever needed to be. You are now asking for data that are private and which we have no business knowing. Flags are anonymous *and should be anonymous*. There is absolutely no benefit in knowing who cast flags or how any flags were cast or anything else. If you have lost respect for the MSE moderators, then maybe you can talk about that, but asking for confidential information is not the right way to go about it.

This isn't about SE Inc doing something against the community's wishes. This was done by one of us, not an employee. Digging into the details will serve no purpose other than to stir up more drama. Robert will be back in a few days and we can move forward. Until then, we have more than enough drama to keep us occupied without trying to start a witch hunt against our fellow users. We've had enough problems because things that should be private have been handled in public. Do we really need yet another episode of the same?

Comment: *There is absolutely no benefit in knowing who cast flags or how any flags were cast or anything else.* Respectfully disagree. Robert Harvey has been suspended mostly because of flags, and it is true that some users have been ganging up in chat to flag comments they disagree with. Shedding more light on what happened is definitely something that must be done now, and that will bring us more understanding about this whole situation I believe.

Comment: 200% agree and Robert is capable. He's capable of discussing this with the CMs if needed. I think it's time we supported the mods that are left on these sites, particularly *this* site, which would be a minefield to moderate at the moment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if you think someone is targeting you, take it up with the mods. Flags are private and confidential and should absolutely remain that way. If you cannot trust the moderation team, I am afraid the only thing to do is leave the site. I would tell you to escalate to SE, but well... So if you can't trust the mods there's really nothing to be done. But making this sort of data public is unacceptable and should _never_ happen.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no, I am telling you that given the current lack of trust in SE, if you also cannot trust the local moderators, then there is nothing anyone can do. Normally, if you distrust the moderators, you would escalate the issue to SE. If you (understandably) also don't trust SE, then there is nobody left to escalate to. But requesting this sort of data is out of line: either you trust the mods and trust them to be fair, or you don't.

Comment: SE should do some _internal_ analysis on finding patterns of coordinated flagging brigades. Especially, since many comments have been targeted and deleted that merely expressed opinions. And, because users with many flags against them are eligible for receiving a penalty or suspension.

Comment: @dfhwze perhaps, yes. But would you believe their conclusions at this point? I trust the MSE moderators more than I trust SE these days. Far more.

Comment: Furthermore, moderators _must_ act in good faith, specifically in these heated moments. SE should perform an _internal_ audit on the actions of moderators and make their own conclusions. Since MSE moderators are appointed, not elected, it's SE's job to supervise. The community can only do so much ...

Comment: @dfhwze yeah, well last time SE tried that, it didn't go too well :) I think asking them to further review MSE mods at this point is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: Moderators, whether appointed or not, mostly act on flags. When you see, say, 10+ "rude or abusive" flags on some comment, it is very easy to believe that comment is indeed problematic (since 10+ users were offended by it). Mob mentality twists this around, and artificially inflates negativeness in the perception of comments that could very well be perfectly fine. *Mods are not to blame in this process* (although IMHO they should have realized something nasty was going on). *Users are.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi mods also go around and see things before they're flagged. And the mob mentality isn't very strong, you just see a comment was flagged and a bunch of usernames, you don't see multiple flags.

Comment: If we start dragging up the details of flagging as suggested in the question, I'll stop flagging.

Comment: no, the reason it blew up is because they libeled a person in a  news article.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster yes, precisely. That falls under the general heading of making public things that should remain private. The talking to the press was just the absolute worst example of that, the trend started by making things public on the network and was taken to the unbelievable and harmful extreme of even talking to the press. I guess I'm arguing that we should do better than SE.

Comment: @terdon no, it's the libel, and outright lies that have people angry.  I'm not going to link the article, or what was stated publicly on the site, but SE told outright, and demonstrably so, lies.  THAT is what has people so damn mad, along with the fact that there has been no apology and the continued insistence that they did nothing wrong, when some of what they did rises to the level of [Libel per se](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1154)

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster I'm not disagreeing. That SE pilloried one of their users to the press is the single most outrageous and offensive thing I have seen this company do in the almost ten years I've been active as a user or a mod. I am just saying that those are the extreme examples of what happens when you start dealing with private things in a public manner. And sharing details of flags that were cast under the assumption that they would be kept private is just more of the same problem. Let's let the private stuff be private.

Comment: @terdon to that point, it's not a public/private thing so much as inconsistency.  With the event that triggered this mess, they at the same time slammed her publicly, while hiding behind their own privacy policy, making it one-sided.  So, I guess I am agreeing to an extent.

Comment: @Mast I think that's the intention of at least some of the people calling for this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi by the way mods can't see 10+ "rude or abusive" flags on some comment, simply because 3 such flags remove comment without any mod intervention. One can argue that this feature carries a risk of misuse but so far the issue wasn't widespread (and I frankly can't see it becoming an issue at all, except for maybe meta and few smaller sites where comments sometimes make more influence than they deserve)

Answer (score 32):

You don't need all these stats. Coordinated flagging of dubious posts and comments has been done and is still done by at least some of those that watch / visit the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

That is nothing new, The Tavern has done that since its inception as far as I'm aware. It's operation is not as codified as it is in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) but I've not noticed that specific posts, comments and/or users were singled out. Despite the friction, heat and occasional fire I still hold the position that the room as a whole tried to act on the content and only referred to users when they proved to have a known track record for being disruptive.

It might well have been the case that the user you point out in your question was discussed in the Tavern or even his comments / posts linked. And given the uptick in regulars over the last 6 to 8 days it would have been easy to collect red-flags, if a comment or post was indeed over the edge.

Do know the transcript of the Tavern is public and so is the Trashcan, feel free to start your investigation there and advise me if I should have handled stuff differently.

Now we wait for the invite only Discord rooms to come forward.

Comment: Do we know that the chat room is the source of the flags? Maybe it was just a spontaneous, concerted action by non chat room users?

Comment: @Trilarion No, nobody knows but I'm familiar with the assumptions and seen similar comments claiming the same prior to this. I always chose to be open about the role a chatroom might have played in any situation so others don't have to assume or speculate I try to hide stuff. Also prevents they need to go digging themselves.

Comment: It may be interesting to see how many of the flags came from users also visiting chat. Of course one should always keep in mind that correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm much more interested in how many came from around the network, from users with fresh accounts.

Comment: I think this practice is bad for the site, especially now, and you should stop it.

Answer (score -10):

### Moderators do not suspend users because of flagged comments.

#### They suspend because the flagged comments are rude.

An auto rude flag is generated when there's too many helpful rude flags against a user. The moderator then manually reviews the user's flagged comments and decides whether or not they are being flagged correctly, i.e. rude and whether action needs to be taken.

As a former moderator on two sites and having handled a lot of comment flags (>75,000 flags in total <sub>**note**</sub>), in fact deleted >100,000 comments on Stack Overflow alone (not including Stack Overflow Meta) I can say, you get used to seeing who regularly flags and their flagging pattern. It's easy to pick up if a user is targeting a particular user unnecessarily and if a mod notices that, they will generally have a word with that user. As targeting a user for flags can be construed as a form of harassment, at the least it waste of moderator time.

There comes a point where the community needs to settle down and trust the remaining moderators left on the sites, particularly on MSE. The site has exploded and they're two mods down.

[Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell) gave her answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336340/310756). Rather than make accusations, perhaps it's time people supported the moderators on the ground trying to keep the site clean. [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336339/why-was-robert-harvey-suspended) has a load of experience on the site. I have the utmost respect for Robert, but that doesn't mean he is flawless. I have no idea whether or not a suspension was warranted, but I trust Tinkeringbell not to go out on a limb in this current climate and state her case as a moderator. If Robert wants to take this further, he is more than capable of doing so.

<sub>**note**: fun fact there are not many people in the history of the sites who have handled more flags. Ergo I understand the flagging system better than most.</sub>

Comment: '*There comes a point where the community needs to settle down and trust the remaining moderators left on the sites, particularly on MSE. The site has exploded and they're two mods down.*' - One could argue that it's a little difficult to trust people when comments, posts, and in some cases, users are disappearing left, right, and center. The reasons we saw in the community wiki post clearly showed that the two examples were not worthy of suspension. [1/2]

Comment: '*Rather than make accusations, perhaps it's time people supported the moderators on the ground trying to keep the site clean.*' - Advocating blind support on the grounds of "keeping the site clean" is also problematic. People should be allowed to question and probe without being accused of stirring up trouble. I think you should extend OP the courtesy to assume good faith because there is no evidence to show the contrary, especially from the likes of @gnat.

Comment: @Script47 I'm saying to trust the elected moderators that stayed on. What is wrong with that? They were ok to trust 3 weeks ago and now they're not. It's got to stop. It gets to a point where people need to decide if they want to stay, as if they hate the site so much posting poisonous comments and flaming suspicion in questions is not helpful. The people on here are the same people.

Comment: @YvetteColomb There are no elected mods on this site, they were appointed.

Comment: Yeh and the downvotes are not targeted. Maybe I should raise a flag asking ig my posts are being targeted for downvotes. I'm sure there will be an apparent pattern there.

Comment: '*They were ok to trust 3 weeks ago and now they're not.*' - A lot can happen in 3 weeks, as we've clearly seen. '*It gets to a point where people need to decide if they want to stay, as if they hate the site so much posting poisonous comments and flaming suspicion in questions is not helpful.*' - Again, I *really* detest that if someone questions the shift in the status-quo then they are tarred with words such as '*poisonous*' or '*flaming suspicion*', to throw your words right back at you, those questioning the shift are still the same folk that they were 3 weeks ago.

Comment: '*Yeh and the downvotes are not targeted. Maybe I should raise a flag asking ig my posts are being targeted for downvotes. I'm sure there will be an apparent pattern there.*' @YvetteColomb the irony here is that the OP was trying to do exactly that, that is, get to the bottom of brigading, yet *you* said '*settle down and trust the moderators*' so why not extend that advice onto yourself, or, admit that there might actually be a problem on either side and investigate it?

Comment: @Script47 that's my whole point! No irony. *sigh* few people on this know me. They think they know me and it's a horrid interpretation of who I am, not really understanding me at all.

Comment: @YvetteColomb This is not intended to be an insult but most people see what they are shown. gnat has shown himself to be extremely scrupulous and genuine, maybe he's just fooled us all and he's really a tyrant looking to destroy the site, but until I've seen evidence of that, I have no reason to doubt that he's not fanning the flames of war and that this question is him just worrying about potential abuses.

Comment: Honestly, all I've been seeing is @YvetteColomb's answers bombarded with downvotes, even when the message that they're trying to convey isn't controversial at all. All she's doing here is stating that the mods tend to locate malicious flagging patterns and take appropriate action when that happens, and that (with the team having shrunk) we need to trust the existing mods to keep the ship afloat, and support them in doing that. +1 I agree with this sentiment

Comment: @KyleFairns I just sent an email to the community team. I'm at that point where I cannot stay on the site (the entire network) the way it is now. It's funny how people are defending Monica without the full facts and I'm being maligned in comments, in chat and with downvotes and funnily, I'm also being flagged. All I ever did was stand up for a minority group. It doesn't affect my life personally, it hurts me to see people marginalised, all for the sake of a few two - four letter pronouns.

Comment: "fun fact there are not many people in the history of the sites who have handled more flags. Ergo I understand the flagging system better than most." - Logical fallacy. To take an analogy, driving on the road for 50 years does not necessarily make you a better driver than most.

Comment: "*An auto rude flag is generated when there's too many helpful rude flags against a user. The moderator then manually reviews the user's flagged comments and decides whether or not they are being flagged correctly*" Is the word *helpful* there in error, or is there some mechanism which marks flags as helpful without a moderator deciding whether they're correct?

Comment: @PeterTaylor enough rude flags from the community will delete a comment, so will post deletion - all the standard comment flags will be marked as helpful.

Comment: @JJJ the other posts are not downvoted in the same way

Comment: @Script47 one of my answers with a score of nearly 500 was deleted.... yeah, trust is not what I'm feeling right now.

Comment: I have seen my comments on Meta disappear. Some have fallen as victims of whole threads, some were carefully pruned. I have no idea if someone flagged them as rude or how close to potential suspension I might be. I have seen other people's comments that I don't consider rude deleted. There is valid concern that some flags were not handled fairly.

Comment: @JJJ top answer is +25/-4, second answer +17/-4 and this answer +16/-20.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC it's like a freakin' horror movie..... Where's Patty?  She was here a minute ago?  maybe the CM's should change their avatars to hockey masks or something

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster what are you referring to? Who is Patty supposed to be?

Comment: @YvetteColomb patty would be the allegorical representation of any generic user/user post/user answer that suddenly disappeared.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster ah I get it. that's funny. To clarify - this suspension appears to be given by a moderator, not a CM. The CMs are deleting the posts, not the mods. The mods are trying to just get through flags as per usual. The CMs are helping handle flags also. But the actual suspension appears to be manually reviewed by a mod.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC there are many defamatory comments about me sitting on the site right now that have not been deleted. So I do agree - the comment deletion is inconsistent. I believe this is from sheer overload. There was a post where Tim Post was handling flags and mentioned having 50 tabs open and not navigating the flag dashboard well. So I don't think the flag deletion is personal, I think it's people handling flags as best they can.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster Agreed. Vanishing posts and comments (and users) certainly don't improve already tense situation.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I can believe there are rude and abusive comments out there. I can certainly understand that in current situation more will be deleted than usual because there are too many. But, in all this chaos it will not help if users get suspended because flags have been handed left and right and possibly unjustly approved.

Comment: To the mod or CM that eventually turns up to clean the comments, please objectively prune only those comments that are useless and don't just purge the whole chain.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC the thing is, I've been accused of coodinated flagging and being responsible for all teh commentz dizappearing - yet I have declined flags! And not all my flags are handled.

Comment: @Script47 I flagged two as NLN as I deleted my comment after reading those comments and agreed and figured, they're NLN. But I am too often being accused of mal-doing. That my motives are malicious. There does come a point when comment discussion is irrelevant - the answer and the votes speak for themselves.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC also - noteworthy - it does appear that an actual moderator suspended Robert - not am employee - I don't think that moderator would make a rash decision in this climate - I'm assuming Tinkeringbell, but she may be answering for Chris (there's only two mods). I would hope she would manually review the comments. When getting an auto too many rude comments flags - we (on SO) would always actually go and read the comments. You can sort by flagged comments, so it's not hard. I did flag some of robert's comments as NLN.

Comment: One thing that might be better is if these long comment threads are moved to chat. People don't like that, but it beats deletion. I suspect it may be easier to hit the "purge all" comments button when facing a back log of hundreds of flags. Things would get hectic on SO, that's for sure, but we had a huge team.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I have seen that. I think it is far from the truth. But to be honest you did make a flop with that "dude" comment flagging (maybe not so much with original flag, but the later post), so people started to jump to the conclusions. If nothing else whatever you do, no matter how _wrong_ it turns out, your original intent is always good.

Comment: @YvetteColomb As for downvotes on your posts. I don't think they are targeted personal attacks (I may be wrong, but I doubt that so many people are specifically targeting you), more disagreement with your opinion.

Comment: @YvetteColomb with all due respect, it seems that panic is the only thing driving most decisions lately. This is of course not helping the level of outrage, and of course, people finding their posts deleted here, are posting on twitter, FB, Devrant, hacker news, reddit, et cet....   not good

Comment: Moderators have lost a lot of trust. For one, acting as a moderator can be seen as being in support or at least accepting of the company's actions, at least more so than the moderators who quit. Two, [enforcing restrictive policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387883/should-the-mod-team-tighten-up-moderation-on-meta-comments) explicitly against the will of a large majority of users removes trust. Three, silencing people and wasting their time through constant comment purges/... also erodes trust. So people trust moderators a lot less than a while ago.

Comment: That reduced trust in moderators might cause people to downvote a post suggesting to just move on and trust the moderators.

Comment: While I can understand your frustration (I have also changed my username, not to prevent others to know who I am, but just for my sake and to feel more personally detached) constant changes of your username are currently not doing you any favors.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC that's not a reason to downvote my posts. That is supporting the view that people are voting on the author not the content. Which is clearly the case for x% of users here.

Comment: Agreed. Content is what matters, not a person. Though in this instance maybe it is disagreement with notion that all comments flagged as rude are really rude. In current climate of distrust that is quite realistic option.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC I don't think all comments flagged as rude are rude - and even if they're marked as helpful they still may not be valid. There's other things - like deleting a post - that will automatically mark a rude comment flag as helpful. So it's important to review them manually if considering suspension. Vital actually.