# What's the Moderator Dashboard look like?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators

I, along with (probably) hundreds of thousands of other Stack Exchange users, ***really really*** want to know what the Stack Exchange Moderator Dashboard looks like.

Moderators are democratically elected, right? The President of the United States is democratically elected, right? We get to see pictures of the Oval Office, right? **So why can't we see screenshots of the Mod Dashboard?**

The only reason Americans can't see the plans for the President's car is that then we would find a vulnerability in it. Then some crazy person would assisinate him.

On SE, however, it's different. Screenshots of the dashboard will not cause us to find vulnerabilities in it and assisinate the moderators.

There is the problem of private info being displayed in it, but the blur tool in Photoshop has to be used sometimes, right?

---

**So, as a citizen of the Stack Exchange Network, I, along with my fellow Exchangiens, ask that we be shown a censored screenshot of the Moderator Dashboard.**

---

We did elect you mods, after all :)

Comment: Just join the next election.

Comment: @Bart Just become President of the United States. That's all you need to do :)

Comment: Given that I wasn't born in the US, that would be impossible. You however actually could become a moderator. I mean, just look at them.... (No, upset moderator, not you. You are the exception)

Comment: I imagine it looks something like the Tools menu that 10k users have access to. Are you expecting some fancy military-grade screen with a big red button to "launch a nuke at this user" for those nasty spam accounts? What benefit comes to you from seeing it?

Comment: @animuson [This at least](http://i.imgur.com/OrSEwOY.gif).

Comment: This might be a somewhat accurate glimpse of it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173585/stack-exchange-needs-a-better-way-to-inform-their-moderators-about-feature-and-p

Comment: It looks pretty much like the /tools dashboard.

Comment: 10K club's /tools page doesn't look all that much different; they just have a higher range of power.

Comment: See this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/how-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator not quite the "dashboard", but interesting.

Comment: @Bart a few elections later, all I can say: Be careful what you wish for! (And kudos to Undo for taking the advice seriously).

Comment: @undo I find it ironic that now you are a moderator, and before you thought it was very unlikely to happen: _"Just become President of the United States.  That's all you need to do :)"_  Now, any super-secret screenshots to share with us (you once had the same question too ;)?  Just kidding.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how flags appear in the mod dashboard:

[image]

We also see (unhandled) flags when we visit the post:

[image]

Everything else is either too boring (recent migrations, recent bounties, recent locks), or has too much private information to share (suspicious voting patterns, recent mod messages / suspensions). I took a screenshot of one of the more interesting parts of the mod dashboard and started blurring stuff and... the only thing that was left to show was a couple of labels.

Comment: btw the [question in the screenshot](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191126/what-is-tabular-programming) remains unanswered, if you have a good answer go for it.

Comment: What color were the labels? ;)

Comment: @Undo All labels in the mod dashboard are black, like a moderator's heart.

Comment: Is the "KILL IT WITH FIRE" comment the flag note? Or a moderator-only comment that is only visible via the moderator dashboard?

Comment: @Rachel Heh, no, but if you make that a feature request I'll upvote it. The flag in the screenshot is a normal mod attention flag, "KILL IT WITH FIRE" is the flag message I typed (uninspired, I know).

Comment: Ack.  Three heavily downvoted answers on that question; the two deleted ones are copypastas from Wikipedia.  Maybe you *should* kill it with fire.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've send an email to the Falcon people to take a look and perhaps give me a comprehensive answer, but haven't heard back yet. The poor answers don't bother me because they were effectively moderated by the community, downvotes and flags did the trick. That said, I'm a bit hesitant to throw a bounty, for some reason it seems the question is very attractive to poor answers and we certainly don't need any more.

Comment: I can't help but notice the Rollback Body button looks out of place.

Comment: @Troyen: That's not a button.  It's a label that gives a visual indication that another mod has already taken some action on the post.

Comment: @Troyen What Robert said. That label shows non-mod-only actions taken on the post by mods (edits, rollbacks, comments, etc). Sometimes it's useful to know that a fellow mod participated on the post in some way, sometimes it's not. In this specific case it's absolutely silly, as I was the one who rolled back an edit to the question, so... it's telling me what I did ;}

Comment: Just curios, what kind of things are in the mod menus?

Comment: @Undo In the mod menus? Just a bunch of links.

Answer (score 36):

[image]

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2837/1288

Seriously though, it would be hard to show a screen shot without heavily editing it to conceal who flagged posts and whose posts were flagged. That's supposed to remain private.  The dashboard itself is essentially just a list of links to flagged posts with a short synopsis of each, who flagged it, who originally posted it, and a few buttons to select what action we want to take.

Comment: Wow. You put up with that for four years? I'd recommend trying to get a raise.

Comment: Yeah Bill, at least double of what you earn now.....

Comment: I'd recommend triple.

Comment: @Bill Why is the team so secretive around a *page on a website?*

Comment: @Undo See my edit for the reason why we're being evasive. Half the information is private, plus there's really not a lot to see.

Comment: @bill Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: I could stare at this for hours! So many paths

Comment: @Undo: The moderator dashboard sounds like (correct me if I'm wrong) the moderator tools available to 10k users (just with additional options), of which there is a screenshot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, that's very similar. The only additional information diamond moderators see is who flagged the post, plus we have more flag types to handle.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: You've just been collecting these things and waiting for the right moment to post them, haven't you?

Comment: ....are those yellow highlighted lines the actual flag messages?

Comment: @Bart They are.  They were entered into the Custom Flag description.  People do actually use flags this way occasionally.

Comment: Wow......just.....wow.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that was from one day.  I just cleared the ones in between to get the shot.  No fakery was involved.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question.  +1 for even more answering it.

Comment: @Bart: Makes you wonder if we need to define the term "moderator" in a glossary somewhere. And for that matter, "question" and "answer" too - people seem to get them mixed up all the time.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: This is an inaccurate depiction. It is not at a carnival.

Comment: So moderation is *dexterity-based*! It's all coming together now...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40kCSxZGMgk

Answer (score 9):

[image: You know part of you wants to implement this]

^^
[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)