# Can users with more than 10k reputation flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, privileges, 10k-tools

Reading [Privileges - Access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

> Users lacking the vote to close privilege can still ask questions to
>   be closed through flagging. Additionally, all users can flag answers
>   to request them deleted.

I got one doubt: do users with >10K reputation have the right to flag a post?

Maybe it sounds like such a stupid question, but my impression is: Although they are the ones handling the flags, letting them flag means that the flag will be handled by another user having this privilege.

Comment: Everyone can flag. Even moderators.

Comment: @Yannis, When mod raise a flag,I think it is not counted in their "helpful" flag am I Correct ?

Comment: @Lucifer - if a mod raises a flag and another mod deems it to be helpful then their count of helpful flags increases. However, mods aren't eligible for the Deputy and Marshal badges.

Comment: ok, I saw few candidate in election, Now after the election still their flag is the same, Its not increasing.

Comment: @Lucifer that's probably because they're not flagging posts. It's only in very rare circumstances that a mod actually needs to raise a flag. Most of the time they are acting on existing flags and if they see something that's flag worthy they'll probably close/delete it straight way.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, So when a mod can direct act on any post then why do he/she needs to raise a flag ?

Comment: @Lucifer - You're missing the point. Mods can flag - on smaller sites it can be useful to add "notes" for other moderators to see later. However, on SO this isn't necessary as there's pretty much always at least one other mod online with whom things can be discussed.

Comment: @ChrisF ,Hmm got it, Thanks.

Comment: @Lucifer - Mods can also flag as spam/offensive if they want to - which automatically deletes the post and gives the user a 100 point reputation penalty - which is a "half way" option between just deleting the post (no penalty on the user) and deleting the account (which is the nuclear option for persistent spammers).

Comment: @Lucifer also keep in mind that moderator can't handle flag he raised himself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That Interesting, I think mods do that to draw attention of other mods and asks for second opinion for that particular post.

Comment: I agree with that, @Lucifer, it can make their decisions more valuable when sharing with another one.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, we can (and yes, I've declined my own flag). However, the fact that we can doesn't really mean we do.

Comment: @Yannis weird, remember seeing somewhere that moderator won't see his own flag in the queue so assumed it means he can't handle it either.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Here's me looking at my own flag in the queue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177221/162704

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can users with more than 10k reputation flag?

Yes. Users with 10K+ reputation can flag questions for the following reasons:

- very low quality
- other
- spam
- offensive

For answers:

- not an answer
- other
- spam
- offensive

Users with 20K+ reputation can [vote to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/187824) instead of flagging it.

Comment: No , we can not handle "other/spam or offensive" type's flag, It is directly handle by mods

Comment: @Lucifer - I am not saying 10K+ can handle this. Read the answer again.

Comment: well user with 15 Rep can also do all above. And Users with 10K+ reputation vote to delete for closed question.

Comment: @Lucifer - You still don't understand either the question or the answer. The question is *Can users with more than 10K reputation flag?* And I am showing available reasons for flagging by 10K.

Comment: Worth to mention that 10K+ users *can* flag as "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" as well. However, if the user still got close votes the flag is automagically converted to close vote.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah. But [the reason I didn't mention it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182284/why-my-flag-get-result-as-none#comment-555098).